# Identify specific condition between rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table in `PostgreSQL` as follow:

```
logid | transactionid | partid | qty  | refid
------+---------------+--------+------+------
 100  |      3        |    50  |   10 | 5555
 101  |      2        |    25  |   5  | 5812
 102  |      3        |    50  |   20 | 5844
 103  |      3        |    10  |  200 | 1234
 104  |      3        |    10  |  100 | 0
 105  |      3        |    10  | -150 | 1234
```

I want to write a query which gives:
rows with `transactionid = 3` and when two following `logid` on the same `partid` one has `refid <> 0` and the **next** has `refid = 0`.

for the above data I want to get:

```
103   |      3         |    10  |  200  | 1234
104   |      3         |    10  |   100 | 0
```

Comment: Window functions - `lag` and `lead`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`LAG` and `LEAD`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-window.html)  window functions to get required result set:

```
SELECT logid, transactionid, partid, qty, refid
FROM (
  SELECT logid, transactionid, partid, qty, refid,
         LAG(partid) OVER (ORDER BY logid) AS prev_partid,
         LAG(refid) OVER (ORDER BY logid) AS prev_refid,  
         LEAD(partid) OVER (ORDER BY logid) AS next_partid,
         LEAD(refid) OVER (ORDER BY logid) AS next_refid
  FROM mytable
  WHERE transactionid = 3) AS t
WHERE (partid = next_partid AND refid <> 0 AND next_refid = 0) OR
      (partid = prev_partid AND refid = 0 AND prev_refid <> 0)
```

Using these functions we can identify consecutive rows having the same `partid` values. We can also easily implement `refid <> 0` and `refid = 0` predicates for previous / next row.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5d23f/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
select *, ((lead(a1) over(partition by partid  order by logid ) = true  ) and refid <> 0 ) a2 
     from (select * , case when refid = 0 then ( lag(refid) over(partition by partid order by logid ) <> 0  ) else null end  A1
                from mytable where transactionid = 3 order by logid 
           )q1 order by logid) q2 where a1 or a2
```

maybe this is a bit simpler? hope this works aswell